# SDK 49 Tensorflow and EXGL Error Model Prediction : EXGL: getParameter() doesn't support gl.34229 yet!\]

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, webgl

I have an issue using Tensorflow and EXGL when i try to execute my object detection Model i get this error using SDK 49 : Error Model Prediction : EXGL: getParameter() doesn't support gl.34229 yet!, that's suggesting that there's an issue with the React Native's OpenGL implementation (EXGL) not supporting an OpenGL operation that TensorFlow.js is attempting to use ?

Import the model :

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      await tf.ready();
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");

      // Load the model and weights
      const modelJson = require("./assets/model/model.json");
      const modelWeights1 = require("./assets/model/group1-shard1of3.bin");
      const modelWeights2 = require("./assets/model/group1-shard2of3.bin");
      const modelWeights3 = require("./assets/model/group1-shard3of3.bin");
      const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
        bundleResourceIO(modelJson, [
          modelWeights1,
          modelWeights2,
          modelWeights3,
        ])
      );
      setDetector(model);
      setTfReady(true);
      tf.enableDebugMode();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading the model:", error);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

HandleDetection  :

```
const handleAIModel = async () => {
  try {
    fadeIn(fadeAnim);
    fadeIn(buttonFadeAnim);
    setLoader(true);
    const fullImageTensor = await processImage(capturedImage.uri);
    const fullImageHeight = fullImageTensor.shape[1];
    const fullImageWidth = fullImageTensor.shape[2];
    const sliceWidth = 640;
    const sliceHeight = 640;
    const scaleX = (capturedImage.width / widthLayout) * scale;
    const scaleY = (capturedImage.height / heightLayout) * scale;
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      canvasRef.current.width = fullImageWidth;
      canvasRef.current.height = fullImageHeight;
      const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
      for (let y = 0; y < fullImageHeight; y += sliceHeight) {
        for (let x = 0; x < fullImageWidth; x += sliceWidth) {
          const sliceDims = [
            Math.min(sliceHeight, fullImageHeight - y),
            Math.min(sliceWidth, fullImageWidth - x),
            3,
          ];
          const imageSlice = tf.slice(
            fullImageTensor,
            [0, y, x, 0],
            [-1, sliceDims[0], sliceDims[1], sliceDims[2]]
          );
          const detections = await detector.executeAsync(imageSlice);
          tf.dispose(imageSlice);
          const [boxes, scores, classes] = await Promise.all([
            detections[4].array(),
            detections[5].array(),
            detections[6].array(),
          ]);
          drawRect(
            boxes[0],
            classes[0],
            scores[0],
            parseFloat(props.sensitivity),
            capturedImage.width,
            capturedImage.height,
            ctx,
            scaleX,
            scaleY,
            x,
            y
          );
          detections.forEach((tensor) => tensor.dispose());
        }
      }
    }
    tf.dispose(fullImageTensor);
    setLoader(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during model prediction:", error);
    setLoader(false);
  }
};
```

expo-env-info 1.0.5
System: OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
Binaries: Node: 20.10.0, Yarn: 1.22.19, npm: 9.6.3
IDEs: Android Studio: AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377
npmPackages: @expo/metro-config, expo, react, react-native
Expo Workflow: managed
I also tried SDK 50 and got the same error.